# DNS/Nameserver issue. Can't ping IP or domain

Tags: domain-name-system, ping

I get this when I ping an IP:

```
21:31:50.136623 IP SITE_IP > 173.194.33.4: ICMP echo request, id 14941, seq 1, length 64
21:31:51.136138 IP SITE_IP > 173.194.33.4: ICMP echo request, id 14941, seq 2, length 64
21:31:52.136118 IP SITE_IP > 173.194.33.4: ICMP echo request, id 14941, seq 3, length 64
21:31:53.136129 IP SITE_IP > 173.194.33.4: ICMP echo request, id 14941, seq 4, length 64
21:31:54.136102 IP SITE_IP > 173.194.33.4: ICMP echo request, id 14941, seq 5, length 64
21:31:55.136153 IP SITE_IP > 173.194.33.4: ICMP echo request, id 14941, seq 6, length 64
```

and when I ping a domain:

```
21:29:33.631583 IP 74.125.189.19.52085 > SITE_IP.domain: 28952 A? google.com.MY_DOMAIN. (42)
21:29:38.626553 IP SITE_IP.42280 > 8.8.4.4.domain: 52435+ A? google.com.MY_DOMAIN. (42)
21:29:38.652675 IP 74.125.189.22.63658 > SITE_IP.domain: 36178 A? google.com.MY_DOMAIN. (42)
21:29:43.631626 IP SITE_IP.48205 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 52435+ A? google.com.MY_DOMAIN. (42)
```

The pinging of a domain is what worries me, because it looks like it is checking my DNS files for the resolution.

Here is etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1               localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
SITE_iP            server.MY_DOMAIN.com server
```

Will also add that I am seeing a number of 'SERVFAIL'..

I have no idea what could be causing this problem.  If there is any other information I need to provide, let me know.  I'm using CentOS.

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
46.249.48.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
0.0.0.0         46.249.48.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
```

ifconfig

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:*
      inet addr:server_ip  Bcast:46.249.48.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: inet6_addr Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: inet6_addr Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:516053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:557877 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:110304822 (105.1 MiB)  TX bytes:520208744 (496.1 MiB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:c0000000-c0012800
```

Answer (score 1):

When you ping a name, `ping` needs to resolve the host or domain name to an IP address first, thus a name lookup is expected. Check `/etc/host.conf` to see where the system looks first. `order:hosts,bind` would check `/etc/hosts` first, `order:bind,hosts` would check DNS first. Also, does the domain name you're trying to ping resolve at all?

Comment: It resolves when I have nameserver 127.0.0.1 in resolv.conf, otherwise, nope.  The only thing in /etc/host.conf is 'multi on'.

Comment: And can you ping the name when you have `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf`? If you can, then there's no address record for the name in public DNS. Adding the line `order:hosts,bind` to your `/etc/host.conf` should fix the issue.

Comment: can't ping anything at all, even IP addresses.. under any circumstance :(

Comment: If you can't even ping IP addresses, there's a problem with your network configuration. Please update your question with the output of `ifconfig` and `route -n`.

Comment: Can you at least reach your gateway (`ping 46.249.48.1`)? According to your `RX` and `TX` counters, your host seems to be able to send and receive packets just fine.